# Detect use of su command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, security

I would like to know if there is anyway to send a mail as soon as someone tries `su -`, `su` or `su root`. I know the mail command and I am trying to write a script but I am very confused as to

- where to write it - whether in `.bashrc` of root or in `/etc/process`
- how to invoke the mail on the use of `su`

I've tried the usual Google search etc. but got links on usage of `su`, disabling it, securing ssh etc - none of which answered this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which distro of Linux are you running?

Comment: Sorry, for got to mention I am using CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a log file called `/var/log/secure` which receives an entry any time `su` is executed. It gets entries under other conditions as well. It's described in the [Linux Administrator's Security Guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_administrators_security_guide/08_Linux_System_and_User_Logging.html).

If user "fred" executes `su -`, an entry will appear which looks something like this:

```
Jul 27 08:57:41 MyPC su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by fred(uid=500)
```

A similar entry would appear with `su` or `su root`.

So you could set up a script which monitors `/var/log/secure` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/secure; do
  if tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep " su: "; then
    tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep " su: " | mail -s "su occurred" you@email.com
  fi
done
```

Note that you need to have the `inotify-tool` package installed to use `inotifywait`.

If this script is running in the background, it should send an email to `you@email.com` any time an `su` entry occurs.

Now where to run the script. One approach would be to put this into an executable script file (say, `watchsu`) and call it from your `rc.local` file:

```
nohup /path/to/watchsu 2>&1 &
```

I'm sure there are other ideas for where to start it. I'm not familiar with CentOS.

Comment: what would be the difference between setting a cron to run this script (maybe every minute) and using inotify? I ask this as I haven't used inotify before.

Comment: @i.h4d35 you could do a `cron` job, but you'd also need to create a script that checked what lines were added to the file since last time it checked it. So there's a bit of logic there you'd have to recreate that `inotify` does for you.

Comment: Thanks. So instead of setting a cron what I did was, I added a call to the script from /etc/rc.local (which would be applied at the time of server reboot) and also ran the script `nohup /path/to/watchsu &` to run as a daemon behind. Also add another if condition to check for "su-l:". This script is now running successfully on our server. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 4):

I guess that your underlying requirement is that you have a bunch of people you have given root privilege to but you don't completely trust them so you want to keep an eye on them. Your solution to this is to get yourself sent mail whenever they become root.

The problem with this solution is that the root user has unlimited privilege and so there's nothing to stop them from counteracting this mechanism. They could for instance, edit the /etc/login.defs file in one session, do the good thing that you want them to do and then later su to root and do the bad thing that you fear and at the end of that session they edit the /etc/login.defs file back to it's original state and you're none the wiser. Alternatively they could just make a copy of /usr/bin/bash and make the copy a suid file that will give them privilege whenever they run it.

You might be able to close any of the vulnerabilities I've just suggested but there will be many, many more. So you either trust them or else don't use su at all and give them sudo permission to run just those commands that they need to do the thing you want them to do.

Comment: The requirement you have outlined is, in essence, correct. I agree with you suggestions as well. The issue here is not something to with the trust factor though. The idea is to develop a mail notification system (for the want of a better term) which notifies different things like ssh, su etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page for su, in /etc/login.defs you can set either `SULOG_FILE file` or `SYSLOG_SU_ENABLE yes` to log all su activity.  Then you just need something like inotifywait to watch the log file for su events.